# Node.js is not working in Reactjs app - nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, debian

Locally everythings is working correct, now im trying to get the node working but i can't

It's my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  54.38.184.210;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://54.38.184.210:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  location / {
    root /root/site/public;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

}
```

http://54.38.184.210/ 
i run - npm run build, then i put all dist files into public, the static content is working, i can see whole website, but the backend is not working, im starting my server using "node index.js"

Maybe im doing something wrong, please help me!

Comment: Have you started server and client side on different ports? Is everything okay?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
server {
         listen 443 ssl;
         server_name 54.38.184.210;
         ssl_certificate {your path to .crt file}/api.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key {your path to .rsa file}/api.rsa;
            location / {
                        proxy_pass 54.38.184.210:8080;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                     }
        }
```

"service nginx restart" to restart your backend nginx